# checked listview items

Tags: c#, winforms

I have Two ListViews...
I have ListView(ListView1) with items, and another one(ListView2) is empty. i need to copy the checked items from ListView1  to ListView2 at the same time i have to remove the checked item in ListView1 using C#...

I am using windows form...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? (Not tested!!)

```
for (int i = ListView1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  if (ListView1.Items[i].Checked)
  {
    ListView2.Items.Add(ListView1.Items[i]);
    ListView1.Items.Remove(ListView.Items[i]);
    // OR
    // ListView1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
  }
}
```

EDIT:
This might be better.

```
CheckedListViewCollection checked = ListView1.CheckedItems
foreach (itm in checked)
{
  ListView2.Items.Add(itm);
  ListView1.Items.Remove(itm);
}
```

Comment: The use of CheckedListViewCollection is nice.

Comment: Your second solution is the perfect way of doing this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
while (listView1.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
{
    ListViewItem item = listView1.CheckedItems[0];
    listView1.Items.Remove(item);
    listView2.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Tested.

Note the order of the item removal and adding. The framework throws up an exception if you try to add a `ListViewItem` to more than one list at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

//Copy ListView

```
for (int i = ListView1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  if (ListView1.Items[i].Checked)
  {
    ListView2.Add(ListView1.Items[i]);
  }
}


//Delete checked 

ListView1.CheckedIndexCollection checkedItemsList = listView1.CheckedIndices;     
while (checkedItemsList.Count > 0)
{
   listView1.Items.RemoveAt(checkedItemsList[0]);
}
```

Bye

Comment: You've got an error in your for loop. Should read i--. Not i++.